# How to properly count React's scroll position, when switching pages?

Tags: reactjs, redux, scroll

I have a function that reads the scroll position and saves to state (Redux). There is a problem, on a page with articles after switching to a certain article for some reason the function captures the wrong scroll position.
To understand: 1200px (scrolling works fine) -> article switching (change to 24px on the /articles)

[image: Console]

Scroll processing function:

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
const { pathname } = useLocation()
const onScroll = useCallback(() => {
    const y = window.scrollY
    dispatch(scrollSaveActions.setScrollPosition({
        position: y,
        path: pathname
    }))
    console.log(y, pathname)
}, [dispatch, pathname])

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
    }
}, [onScroll])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing scroll position accurately can be a complex task due to various factors involved in web applications. While I can't provide a one-size-fits-all solution for your specific scenario without a deep understanding of your application's structure, I can offer some best practices and code improvements that should help you capture scroll positions more reliably.Debouncing Scroll Events: To avoid capturing too many scroll events and reduce potential performance issues, you can debounce the onScroll function using a library like Lodash. Here's the code:

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

const onScroll = useCallback(
  debounce(() => {
    const y = window.scrollY;
    dispatch(scrollSaveActions.setScrollPosition({ position: y, path: pathname }));
  }, 200), // Adjust the debounce delay as needed
  [dispatch, pathname]
);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  };
}, [onScroll]);
```

Ensure that you're capturing the scroll position after the new article content has fully loaded and rendered. You might need to use an event or a callback to know when the article content is ready.